# Как выполнить возврат ключа словаря, чей вложенный словарь удовлетворяется требованию ключ = значение

Tags: python, словари, dict

Есть словарь

```
test = {1: "Void", 2: {"1": "good1", 2: "good2", 3: "good3"}}
```

Мне надо вернуть самый верхний кей этого словаря, при условии что во вложенном ниже в него словаре есть нужное мне значение. Как это сделать наиболее правильно?
Я пока написал так, но выглядит как жуткий костыль:

```
def test_fun(input_dict):
for key in input_dict:
    if "1" in input_dict[key] and input_dict[key]["1"] == "good1": return input_dict[key]
print(test_fun(test))
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно через генератор и проверку на то, является переменная словарем.
Не сказать, что по памяти оптимально)

```
test = {1: "Void", 2: {"1": "good1", 2: "good2", 3: "good3"}}
ret_key = [key for key, value in test.items() if isinstance(value, dict) and value.get('1') == 'good1']
>>> ret_key
[2]
```

либо можете создать функцию, где изначально будете указывать ключ и значение

```
def return_key(your_dict, key_of, val_of):
   return [key for key, value in your_dict.items() if isinstance(value, dict) and value.get(key_of) == val_of]

>>> print(*return_key(test, '1', 'good1'))
2
```